# Highlighting my active tag

Tags: html, css

I am still pretty new to coding and feel proud of my progress. I have searched and searched to no avail for a solution to my problem. My navigation tabs work correctly, but I can't seem to figure out how to make my active page tab be the same color as the hover color. I used the code from an article at http://blixt.org/articles/tabbed-navigation-using-css#section=introduction. I contacted the author, but have not received a response from him. The only solutions I have found entail completely changing my code to one without using the tabs. I have tried working within the "inspect element" feature, but have made no progress. My webiste is http://actonrecovery.com/. Please help if you can.

Here is my html code:

```
<!--my ordered list for a table of contents TOC-->
<ol id="toc">
<li><a href="recovery.html" id=“recovery”><span>Coach</span></a></li>
<li><a href="coaching.html" id=“coaching”><span>What Is Coaching?</span></a></li>
</ol>
```

Here is my css:

```
/*style the default state for each list item (tab) inside the TOC*/
ol#toc { height: 2em; line-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
/*padding the left part so it won't be covered by the background image of the <a> element*/
ol#toc a { background: #bdf url(tabs.gif); color: #008; display: block; float: left; height: 2em; padding-left: 10px; text-decoration: none; }
ol#toc a:hover { background-color: #3af; background-position: 0 -120px; }
ol#toc a:hover span { background-position: 100% -120px; }
ol#toc li { float: left; margin: 0 1px 0 0; }
/*offset the tab image when a tab is selected*/
ol#toc li.current a { background-color: #48f; background-position: 0 -60px; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; }
ol#toc li.current span { background-position: 100% -60px; }
ol#toc span { background: url(tabs.gif) 100% 0; display: block; line-height: 2em; padding-right: 10px; }
```

Comment: Do you have a separate HTML file for each page in the tab menu?

Comment: Yes, each page is a separate HTML file

Answer (score 2):

According to your css, you should add class `current` to `li`

```
<ol id="toc">
 <li><a href="recovery.html" id="recovery"><span>Coach</span></a></li>
 <li class="current"><a href="coaching.html" id="coaching"><span>What Is Coaching?</span></a></li>
</ol>
```

Also, your `id` has some other type of quote(” ”), change it to normal quotes(" ")

Comment: @Buffyrls Take a look at the above jsfiddle, demos how it works.

Comment: @showdev Thanks so much for your response. I added the <li class="current"> before my <a href...>. The only difference I saw in the CSS was the addition of list-style:none; in the initial ol#toc. It's still not working. Am I missing something else?

Comment: @Buffyrls If you are referring to the Home page of your site, it looks like you applied the "current" class to *all* of the `<li>` elements. Only apply the "current" class to the `<li>` that is "current" (i.e. the page you are currently viewing).

Comment: @showdev DUH! I knew it was something simple. Thanks again for your help. I also look forward to using jsfiddle.net for my next project.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add your 'current' class with the same background color as your hover pseudocode. I created a jsfiddle to show you what I mean.

HTML:

```
<ol id="toc">
<li><a href="recovery.html" id=“recovery”><span>Coach</span></a></li>
<li><a href="recovery.html" id=“recovery”><span>Coach</span></a></li>
<li><a href="recovery.html" id=“recovery”><span>Coach</span></a></li>
<li class="current"><a href="coaching.html" id=“coaching”><span>What Is Coaching?</span>    </a></li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
li {
  background: #bdf;
  color: #008
}
li:hover {
  background: #48f;
}
.current {
 background: #48f;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rynslmns/A29cC/1/

You would need to add your current class to your html for the current page you would like to show 'current'

Answer (score 1):

On the tab that is active, just it's class to "active" or whatever else you want to call it.
Like this:

**HTML:**

```
<!--my ordered list for a table of contents TOC-->
<ol id="toc">
<li><a href="recovery.html" id=“recovery”><span>Coach</span></a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="coaching.html" id=“coaching”><span>What Is Coaching?</span></a></li>
</ol>
```

**CSS:**

```
li 
{
  background: #bdf;
  color: #008
}

li:hover 
{
  background: #48f;
}
.active 
{
 background: #48f;
}
```

That is what I did for my website.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a static HTML and CSS page you could add the .current class to the current pages tab. For example on the home page add the current class to the home page tab, etc. etc.